# Grouping table by column value in R

Tags: r

I'm sorry for the newbie question but I cannot find an answer.

I have a table with 3 columns:

```
File  Word  Occurrences
  f1   cat            2
  f1   dog            1
  f2   cat            4
  f2   pig            3
```

And I want to convert it in a table where each file corresponds to a row and each column to the occurrences of a specific word:

```
File  Cat  Dog  Pig
  f1    2    1    0
  f2    4    0    3
```

Comment: The urls are not the exact dupes.

Comment: @akrun  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5890831/3710546, from first link.

Comment: @Pascal Thanks for that url.  But as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33636641/combine-multiple-rows-with-same-field-in-r/33636750#33636750), it is not a valid reason to close the question (this link was also closed and then reopened based on that).

Comment: @akrun It is your viewpoint that it is not a dupe. It is for me. That's all.

Comment: @Pascal I didn't say it is your viewpoint.  But, you can close it.  I will undupe it. :-)

Comment: @Pascal It is also not my viewpoint.  It is based on the precedence in that link.

Comment: My point is that if another clear dupe can be unduped, this can be too.

Comment: @akrun, for what reason? Just because a mistake was possibly made somewhere else (by "unduping" a duplicate), doesn't mean it should be repeated elsewhere. That's at least my opinion..

Comment: @akrun, I don't see anything put forward by Ananda here and I don't know what other question you referred to. My comment was general

Comment: @docendodiscimus  It is there in the discussion `@Frank, would you know that xtabs sums without either trying it out or trying to interpret the help page for xtabs?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
library(reshape2)
 dcast(df1, File~Word, value.var='Occurrences', sum)
```

Or

```
 xtabs(Occurrences~File+Word, df1)
```

Comment: Thanks, both solution works! I have used the second

Answer (score 2):

my try without additional packages:

```
d <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
'File  Word  Occurrences
f1   cat            2
f1   dog            1
f2   cat            4
f2   pig            3')
d.w <- reshape(d, dir="wide", idvar="File", timevar="Word")
d.w[is.na(d.w)] <- 0
d.w
```

Comment: Thanks, even this is working!